# Invitation to nonkosher restaurant

Tags: kashrut-kosher, employment, marit-ayin, parnassah-livelihood, restaurant

[The question "Keeping Kosher at a secular company"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8794) asks about food issues on the job in general.  This question is focused more narrowly on "unbalanced" situations: situations where there's an imbalance of power.

A junior employee, such as an intern, works at a large company where the senior management sometimes invites junior employees to lunch.  Such meetings are primarily of benefit to the invitees, who can gain valuable advice and networking opportunities as they start their careers.

How should the employee in this situation respond if the invitation is to a non-kosher restaurant?  On the one hand, the lunch offers an opportunity and it seems impolite to decline a higher-up like a company president.  On the other hand, it also seems impolite to sit in the restaurant and not order anything, and this may make a bad impression on those present.   I know there may also be the issue of [maras ayin](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7459/5) from going into and/or eating in the restaurant.

What is the best way to handle this situation?

Comment: duplicate? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/208/759

Comment: This is a valuable question, but you should modify it to be more general rather than personal advice - see http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/312/perhaps-the-community-moderators-should-enact-a-more-strict-policy-regarding-hal/314#314 -- and ask your rav!

Comment: @DoubleAA, this is more about the practical approach. It sounds familiar anyway, but until I find it I can't vote to close as a dupe.

Comment: Any reason this should not be closed as a duplicate of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8794? (ping @DoubleAA)

Comment: @SethJ ping also

Comment: @yitznewton ping also

Comment: @msh210 Good find. Looks like a dupe to me. I think you should ping MonicaCellio below and allow her to edit the answer slightly to better match that question before merging it into there. I don't see a need to bring the other answer along in a merge.

Comment: @msh210, I concur with Double AA.

Comment: @DoubleAA All answers get merged in a merge. If one is no good, it will be downvoted and people will then be able to vote to delete it if they think it merits deletion.

Comment: @msh210, who gets to vote to delete? I don't.

Comment: @msh210 Are you sure this is a dupe? It seems to me that this question introduces the dimension of a large power difference between the inviter and the invited, which could result in significantly different advice on how to conduct oneself.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, hm, good point. Well, it shoulda been closed as too-localized anyway. But once that's cleaned up (it's generalized), I guess you're right that it should be reopened. Perhaps the edited question should emphasize the unique points of this question.

Comment: @SethJ oh sorry: [it's at 20,000 rep points](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/privileges/trusted-user). I thought it was at 10,000, but [that](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools)'s only deletion of questions.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, I had that thought, too, but it would need to be edited to make that the central point. Would the building of collegial relations with fellow interns be relevant to the new angle of the question?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need to jump straight to declining the invitation.  There might be things you can eat, and even if not you won't be impolite to the restaurant by joining a paying group.  The key is to communicate clearly.  You can explain to the person who invited you -- or, more likely, his administrative assistant -- that you would be delighted to come to the lunch but will be unable to eat due to dietary restrictions.  Then go anyway; it's the meeting that's important, not the food.

There might be things you can eat and drink there -- cold drinks are usually safe, for instance, and some salads might be.  Consult your rabbi for specific advice.  The restaurant might also permit you to bring your own food (and dish/cutlery) if you arrange it in advance.

If you have a close connection to the administrative assistant, you might be able to propose a different, kosher restaurant.  But that would be more risky in an unbalanced power structure where you don't know the admin either.

You're right to be concerned about marit ayin.  There are several factors that could affect this and you should discuss them with your rabbi:

- The extent to which this is a career-relevant meeting
- Whether there are easy kosher alternatives (if not it might not be as bad)
- What the prevailing practices/norms in the community are
- How visible you'll be (it's even possible that a Jew visibly having only a glass of water is not only not negative but positive, depending on circumstances)

Ohr Somayach's Ask The Rabbi service tackled a [related question](http://ohr.edu/explore_judaism/ask_the_rabbi/ask_the_rabbi/4439) and points to the book *After the Return* by Rabbi Mordechai Becher and Rabbi Moshe Newman.  (I've read it but don't remember the details of what it said on this question.)

Comment: Thanks! I went and just had water, and it was clear based on the age disparity of the people meeting, the clothes we were wearing, and the time of day that this was a business-related meeting and that I was not eating anything.

Comment: @Daniel, thanks for reporting on what happened.

Answer (score -12):

I mostly agree with the [Monica Cellio](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/17947/1059). Marit ayin should never a problem; see my answer to [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16108/1059). For the sake of kavod haberiyot, you may eat things that are non-kosher rabbinically (but not biblically treyf), if it would please your employers and co-workers. But that is prohibited if they would not get any *hana'ah* (benefit) from eating together with you, or if you want to be strict personally (but that is beyond what the halakhah requires). This is based on the principle suggested by the Gemara in Perek Gimel (?) of Masechet Brachos that says kavod habriyos is docheh (pushes off) *Lo Sasur*. However, there is probably food that you can eat that is even kosher rabinically. Either way, you could always order a diet coke, which is the [advice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halakha) [suggested](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posek) by [Charlie Harary](http://bit.ly/ME0ecw) in this shiur/Q&A entitled **[Preparing for the Workforce: A Candid Discussion about the Unique Challenges and Opportunities a Committed Jew Encounters in the Workplace](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/773134/)**.

Comment: Why the -1, you don't like Charlie Harary?

Comment: If you're going to suggest that people can eat non-kosher if they can justify it based on something as nebulous as kavod haberiyot, you'd best provide a source that both justifies this position and provides details about when and how it may apply.

Comment: I didn't say they could eat shrimp.

Comment: @IsaacMoses - The Gemara there says that being docheh kavod haberiyos can let a Kohein walk over cemetery of tumah derabbanan and jump over the graves! That is a big issur derabbanan.

Comment: I think that stringency (pain) vs. leniency (pain) depends partially on the enforcement of derabbanans: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16692/1059

Comment: Who's kavod habriyot is this: yours or your coworkers?

Comment: @DoubleAA - It shouldn't matter; it is inhumane to allow others to live a [life of pain](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16692/1059).

Comment: [Correction](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17945/invitation-to-nonkosher-restaurant/17949#comment42180_17949): Stringency is pain and leniency is pleasure. But some people who are OCD think that stringency is pleasure and leniency is pain. You have to use your judgment so as not to inflict pain on others.

Comment: Are you saying that maras ayin doesn't exist?

Comment: @Daniel - Yes, I am saying that. Cf: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/17952/1059

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/17958/1059

Comment: @AdamMosheh, in that case, you're disputing centuries of tradition and thousands of pages of literature. If you do so based only on your own reasoning or that of an unidentified contemporary rabbi, you shouldn't be surprised if you get downvotes.

Comment: Adam, I don't know on what basis you can possibly say that there is no such thing as Marith 'Ayin. It's indisputable that the institution exists, was set up as a fence around the Torah, and [has been used in Halachic literature for centuries (if not millennia)](http://ohr.edu/5080#_edn1).

Comment: I can't understand suggesting someone to eat non-kosher food. Even if the issur is only derabbanan, I don't think, imho, it is possible to by-pass it to consider kavod haberioth? what do you do with all rabinical decisions regarding non-Jewish bread, wine ?